# Combining queries by nesting

Tags: sql, nested

With the below query I’m obtaining the PRICE from the table “PRICING”… I have to create the USER ID so that it can be used to JOIN to the second table titled “DEMORAPHICS”
What I want is to take the “Total Cost” I’ve obtained from this below query

```
Select concat(b.ID_Symbol, ' ', b.ID_Number) AS 'UserID’,
SUM(a.Price) AS 'Total Cost'
From Pricing        a 
Left Join User_Info b On a.unique = B.unique
```

What I have:

```
USER ID Total Cost
A22     100
B33     200
C44     300
```

…and attach it to this below query

```
Select
UserID
Name,
Address,
Phone
FROM Demographics
```

What I want:

```
USER ID  Name       Address      Phone      Total Cost
A22      John Doe   777 5th St   555-5555   100
B33      Sammy Singh222 3rd Blvd 555-5000   200
C44      Melissa Doe555 1st ave  555-5500   300
```

I’m not sure how and where to and how to nest the query if that is even the right approach… a little help?

Comment: Side notes: **1.** Why a left outer join? You seem to want a mere inner join. **2.** `AS 'UserID'` and `AS 'Total Cost'` is invalid SQL. The standard name delimiter is the double quotes: `AS "UserID"`. **3.** Please choose mnemonic alias names for the tables (e.g. `from pricing p` instead of `from pricing a`). Alias names shall increase a query's readablility not decrease it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Another thing I noticed is the use of `CONCAT` function. If you're using Oracle then it's incorrect as `CONCAT` accepts only 2 values.

You can also do this with bit lengthy approach of creating CTEs. You haven't tagged DB but this is a generic solution:

```
with cte1 as
(
  Select
    b.ID_Symbol || ' ' || b.ID_Number AS 'UserID',
    SUM(a.Price) AS 'Total Cost'
  From Pricing a 
  Left Join User_Info b On a.unique = B.unique
  group by b.ID_Symbol, b.ID_Number
)
,cte2 as
(
  Select UserID, Name, Address, Phone
  FROM Demographics
)
select b.UserID, b.Name, b.Address, b.Phone, a."Total Cost"
from cte1 a
join cte2 b on a.UserID=b.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

### With a subquery in the select clause:

```
select userid, name, address, phone,
  (
    select sum(price)
    from pricing p
    join user_info ui on ui.unique = p.unique
    where concat(ui.id_symbol, ' ', ui.id_number) = d.userid
  ) as total
from demographics d;
```

### With a subquery in the from clause:

```
select d.userid, d.name, d.address, d.phone, up.total
from demographics d
join
(
  select concat(ui.id_symbol, ' ', ui.id_number) as userid, sum(price) as total
  from pricing p
  join user_info ui on ui.unique = p.unique
  group by concat(ui.id_symbol, ' ', ui.id_number)
) up on up.userid = d.userid;
```

Comment: Wouldn't a group by or order by be required because of the SUM?

Comment: @shade206: The first subquery is correlated, i.e. it refers to the row in the main query (`where ... = d.userid`). We only select one value hence for the one userid and don't need `GROUP BY` here. You can imagine this as a loop; for every userid from `demographics` the subquery is run. The second query on the other hand works with `GROUP BY`, because I am calculating the total per userid and join these to the `demographics` rows.

Comment: And `ORDER BY` has nothing to do with aggegation. The only valid place for an `ORDER BY` would be at the end of the queries and it would merely sort the results and not affect them in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want an additional `join`:

```
select d.UserID, d.Name, d.Address, d.Phone,
       SUM(p.Price) AS TotalCost
from Pricing p join
     User_Info ui
     on p.unique = ui.unique join
     demographics d
     on d.userid = concat(ui.ID_Symbol, ' ', ui.ID_Number)
group by d.UserID, d.Name, d.Address, d.Phone
```